# How to wait for data in useEffect hook before displaying it?

Tags: reactjs, axios, chart.js, use-effect

So my problem is quite simple I think, but I don´t really know how to fix it.

I´m trying to display a set of data insice a ChartJS line chart, but I have a proble retreiving the data.

Here's what the API call output looks like:

```json
{
    "total": 4294496256,
    "valores": [
        {
            "time": "2022-06-01T07:00:00Z",
            "value": 2535383574.2608695
        },
        {
            "time": "2022-06-01T07:15:00Z",
            "value": 2544284512.711111
        },
        {
            "time": "2022-06-01T07:30:00Z",
            "value": 2537325454.2222223
        },
        {
            "time": "2022-06-01T07:45:00Z",
            "value": 2543294555.022222
        },
        {
            "time": "2022-06-01T08:00:00Z",
            "value": 2543005058.8444443
        },
        {
            "time": "2022-06-01T08:15:00Z",
            "value": 2548481774.9333334
        },
        {
            "time": "2022-06-01T08:30:00Z",
            "value": 2544248149.3333335
        },
        {
            "time": "2022-06-01T08:45:00Z",
            "value": 2543528618.6666665
        },
        {
            "time": "2022-06-01T08:56:06.1293542Z",
            "value": 2541892416
        }
    ]
}
```

I retreive the total value to set the max value for the y axis, and I need to loop trough all the "valores" and push them to an array.

Here's the code used for the useEffect call:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "http://192.168.10.88:3000/test/memory?intervalo=1h&servidor=192.168.2.138&filtro=-1h"
      );
      const gbMaximo = Number(res.data.total / 1000 / 1000 / 1000);
      setMaximo(gbMaximo);
      let ejex = [];
      let valores = [];
      res.data.valores.map((valor) => {
        const tiempoFormateado = new Date(valor.time).toLocaleTimeString();
        ejex.push(tiempoFormateado);
        const gb = Number(valor.value) / 1000 / 1000 / 1000;
        const gbFinal = gb.toFixed(2);
        valores.push(gbFinal);
    });
    setLabels(ejex);
    setDatasets(valores);
    };

    getData()
  }, []);
```

Everything else is working fine, but when I try to go to the website, i can only see 2 or 3 values.

My guess is that the useEffect is not waiting untin the completion of the function getData, but I don´t really know how to fix it as I can´t make the useEffect hook run an async function.

Thanks you for the help!

Comment: are you getting all the data in "res" variable, try to console.log() it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
     const res = await axios.get(
      "http://192.168.10.88:3000/test/memory?intervalo=1h&servidor=192.168.2.138&filtro=-1h"
    );
     return res;
  }
  const getData = async () => {
    let res = await fetchData();
    const gbMaximo = Number(res.data.total / 1000 / 1000 / 1000);
    setMaximo(gbMaximo);
    let ejex = [];
    let valores = [];
    res.data.valores.map((valor) => {
      const tiempoFormateado = new Date(valor.time).toLocaleTimeString();
      ejex.push(tiempoFormateado);
      const gb = Number(valor.value) / 1000 / 1000 / 1000;
      const gbFinal = gb.toFixed(2);
      valores.push(gbFinal);
  });
  setLabels(ejex);
  setDatasets(valores);
  };

  getData()
}, []);
```

And sure, you can define the functions outside the `useEffect`